# Write Apex Trigger more efficiently

Tags: apex-code

I am writing a trigger on an object (Object1__c) that will split a single row inserted into Object1__c
into multiple rows and do an insert into another object i.e. Object2__c

Basically a single line corresponding to 12 months (a year) of data has to be split into 12 monthly rows of data for the other object.

Currently I am using the crude way of splitting up as below.

Is there any efficient way of achieving this?

```
Trigger trgSplit on Object1__c (After Insert){


List<Object2__c> object2List = new List<Object2__c>;


For(Object1__c nc : [select Account_Number__c, Account_Name__c,  Y1M01__c,Y1M03__c,Y1M04__c,Y1M05__c,Y1M06__c,Y1M07__c,Y1M08__c,Y1M09__c,Y1M10__c,Y1M11,Y1M12__c])    {

Object2__c pc = new Object2__c();


pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M01__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('01/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);

pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M02__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('02/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);


pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M03__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('03/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);


pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M04__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('04/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);

pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M05__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('05/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);


pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M06__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('06/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);


.............................................


//and so on

//upto 


pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M11__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('11/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);


pc = new Object2__c();
pc.Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c;
pc.Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c;
pc.Total__c = nc.Y1M12__c;
pc.Record_Date__c = date.parse('12/01/2014');
object2List.add(pc);

}

     insert object2List;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get at sObject fields directly via the property name `nc.Y1M01__c`, or by the underlying sobject's get method `nc.get('Y1M01__c')`.  Since you can pass a string dynamically you can now use a loop to get rid of the code re-use:

```
List<Object2__c> object2List = new List<Object2__c>;

For(Object1__c nc : [select Account_Number__c, Account_Name__c,  Y1M01__c,Y1M03__c,Y1M04__c,Y1M05__c,Y1M06__c,Y1M07__c,Y1M08__c,Y1M09__c,Y1M10__c,Y1M11,Y1M12__c]) {
    //loop thru each month, 1...12
    for(Integer i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        //get the month and prefix a zero if necessary
        String month = String.valueOf(i);
        month = (month.length() == 1 ? '0' : '') + month;

        //build the date
        Date recDate = Date.parse(String.format('{0}/01/2014', new List<String> { month }));

        //get the field api name
        String y1mXX = String.format('Y1M{0}__c', new List<String> { month }));
        //get the field value, you will need to cast it to the appropriate data type
        Decimal y1mXXval = Decimal.valueOf( String.valueOf( nc.get(y01mXX) ) );

        //since you are not using the new Object2__c anymore just pass it directly into the list
        object2List.add(new Object2__c(
            Account_Number__c = nc.Account_Number__c,
            Account_Name__c = nc.Account_Name__c,
            Total__c = y1mXXval,
            Record_Date__c = recDate
        ));
    }

}

insert object2List;
```